# Open Edx update logo

Tags: openedx

I am trying to change logo image on my Edx site.
I go to folder /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/static/images/default-theme
and upload new logo image, but when I update website, my logo is not updated

also I restarted lms and cms, but it doesnt help to solve a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dmitri you are using the wrong path, to change logo :

1. Go to the `/edx/var/edxapp/staticfiles/images/`
2. Replace the image `header-logo.png` with new logo image. 
   Note : filename and file extension should stay `header-logo` and `png`, respectively?
3. Restart the LMS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should run collectstatic

```
sudo -H -u edxapp bash

source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env

cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform

python manage.py cms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput

python manage.py lms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't hard code logo.

I would recommend using the theme for a logo change.

We can compile the code.

sudo -H -u edxapp bash

source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env

cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform

paver update_assets cms --settings=production

paver update_assets lms --settings=production

sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl status all