# Changing Bitnami Open edX Logo

Tags: bitnami, openedx

I'm new to Bitnami and Open edX and I'm having trouble changing the logo. I'm new at this and was experimenting with adopting the red-theme that comes with it and changing preexisting values for styling (which I did successfully). However, I am unable to change the logo without the site crashing and giving a 500 error after about a minute or so.

This happened when I replaced `~/apps/edx/var/staticfiles/red-theme/images/logo.3364725269f9.png` with my own, with the same filename. It's odd, because it works for about a minute or two and looks perfect. But, when I refresh about 3 minutes later, the site doesn't load. I also tried replacing the logos in ~/apps/edx/var/staticfiles/images as well as `~/apps/edx/edx-platform/themes/red-theme/lms/static/images`, but nothing has worked.

Lastly, I've tried following the directions here:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900783/open-edx-update-logo`
`https://community.bitnami.com/t/trying-to-add-organization-logo/41865`
`https://community.bitnami.com/t/changing-the-open-edx-organization-logo/50790`
but to no avail. Each time I change it, I have been recompiling the assets, just to make sure.

Also, this is my first stackoverflow post ever, so please let me know ways I could improve my questions; I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

If you access your `/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log` file you should see an error like:

```
The name 'red-theme/images/logo.png' could not be hashed with ...
```

I was able to make it work by substituting both `/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/var/staticfiles/red-theme/images/logo.3364725269f9.png` and `/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/var/staticfiles/red-theme/images/logo.png`, and then update LMS assets by running:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/bin/edxapp-update-assets-lms
```

I hope it helps